# Uniform distribution in probability spaces

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

$X$ is a random variable defined on probability space $(\Omega, P)$.

Assume that $X \sim U(\{1,2,3\})$.

Then $(\Omega, P)$ is a uniform probability space.

I need to prove or to disprove this.

I need some help to get me going, I don't even know how to start here.
Thanks!

Comment: What is a uniform probability space?

Comment: It means that the probability of picking an event is equal among all events

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider $\Omega = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ and the measure $P$ that satisfies $P(\{0\}) = (\{1\}) = \frac{1}{3}$ and $P(\{2\}) = P(\{3\}) = \frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an important component of your probability space. They should always have the three components: $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. In your case, the sample space $\Omega = \left\{1,2,3\right\}$, the sigma-algebra is
$$\mathcal F = \left\{\emptyset, \left\{1\right\}, \left\{2\right\}, \left\{3\right\}, \left\{1,2\right\}, \left\{1,3\right\}, \left\{2,3\right\}, \left\{1,2,3\right\}\right\}$$
Additionally, the definition of the uniform distribution is that $P(A) = \dfrac {|A|} {|\Omega|}$,  $\forall A \in \mathcal F$. But your told that $X \sim U(\{1,2,3\})$ which means $P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=\dfrac 1 3$. It's then straightforward to show that this linear constraint on $P$ implies that $P(A) = \dfrac {|A|} {|\Omega|}$ which is all you need to show.

Comment: It is nowhere written that $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}$. $\Omega$ is just the space on which $X$ is defined.